# Notify Operator when scene property update

Tags: python

I want to call a method of an operator when a scene property has changed.

I know there is an update callback:

```
bpy.types.Scene.h_dock = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    items = h_dock, name="Dock", 
    description="Dock to left or right side", 
    default="0", update=???)
```

But how to add a method of an operator here or any other class/instance in which I have to update member variables?

Thx

Comment: You have to write a function which takes 2 arguments (self, context) and executes whatever you need - and pass it as the 'update' argument

Answer (score 0):

here is how i did it in my addon, i registerd my property's in directly in the register def and made a def at the top of my script that gets called when the value of the property changes

```
def Update_BoolProp(self, context):
    pass
bpy.types.Object.BoolProp = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
    name="BoolProp",
    description="description",
    default = True,
    update = Update_BoolProp
    )
```

i think that you can define the update function where ever you like as long as you can access where you define your property's.

ps: your vids are really helpful

Comment: Cheers. Unfortunately now you have turned it into a recursion loop, by updating the property in its own update method.  A good way to toggle bools is `flag = not flag`